# Detecting keyup

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, input

If I type:

```
$ xinput test 14
```

and press and hold <kbd>return</kbd>, I get:

```
key release 36
key press   36

key release 36
key press   36

...
```

until I release.

#### Questions

- Is it possible to detect when I actually release the key?
- For example, could I write a command that would wait for me to release
  return before finishing?

Comment: Disable key repeat then try again. (like shift)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `xev` it shows KeyPress and KeyRelease events.

While hitting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> aka. <kbd>Super</kbd> key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xae00001,
    root 0x2ca, subw 0x0, time 595467354, (98,77), root:(102,443),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0xae00001,
    root 0x2ca, subw 0x0, time 595467453, (98,77), root:(102,443),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```